# Getters cannot be used to identify return type properly in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, compiler-warnings, getter

I have a data class that has the following form:

```
data class ContentElementField(val type: String) {
    val text: String? = null
        get() = requireNotNull(field)
    val style: String? = null
        get() = requireNotNull(field)
    val path: String? = null
        get() = requireNotNull(field)
    val caption: String? = null
        get() = requireNotNull(field)
}
```

The problem arises when I want to perform the following operation:

```
when (it.type) {
    "text" -> TextElement(Text(it.text), Style(it.style))
    "image" -> ImageElement(Path(it.path), Caption(it.caption))
}
```

The compiler warns me about that `You cannot send a nullable type to a function that does not accept nullable arguments.`

Even if the field is signed to be nullable, its getter is signed to be not nullable, though.

The compiler should use getters to resolve whether to give this warning.

What would you offer to get around this problem?

Comment: Hard to tell what you're trying to do from the code shown, because it doesn't really make sense. Since these properties are read-only `val`s, there's no way to change the backing field so they can only ever be null.

Comment: Of course, it makes sense. The data classes are used by a JSON library. Two of those fields are set together as it turns out in the `when` statement. That means when the type is determined accordingly, the fields accessed are determined to be not null. Otherwise, the error is thrown.

Comment: The getter's return type is always exactly equal to the type of the property, unfortunately.  You're not going to be able to do this without rearranging things -- e.g. having a `private val _caption: String?; val caption: String get() = field!!`

Comment: If you can arrange for the fields to be set _at_ initialisation, rather than after, then you can make them non-nullable, and the code will be simple and clear and you won't have to go to all this trouble to fool the type system. (That could be in initialisers, or an `init` block, or a secondary constructor, or a factory method, or a `@PostConstruct` method. Or if there's really no way to get their values until after the class has been constructed, and you're not using a framework such as Spring, then you could make them `lateinit`.)

Comment: Ideally if you have one field that effectively defines the type of another couple of fields (by making them non-null types) then you'd define specific classes or whatever matching those possible combos and the data they *do* include, and create the appropriate one depending on your data. Creating one class that's meant to represent different things with their own rules about its properties is just complicating things for yourself, and losing a lot of the benefits of the type system. I don't know what library you're using but there has to be a way to conditionally construct different classes

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter if your getter *happens to* crash if the current value is *null* - the type is still *nullable*, the getter's return type is still `String?`.

Why are you doing this anyway? Why not just make the fields non-null as normal and let a *null* assignment throw the exception instead? That way you won't have to fight the type system.

If what you have in mind is different and this was just meant to be a simple example, then you have a few options:

- Use `!!` at the call site since you're guaranteeing it's not null

```
"text" -> TextElement(Text(it.text!!), Style(it.style))
```

- Expose the private nullable property through a non-null one:

```
// I see people do this a lot in Activities and Fragments even though
// they should probably just be making the one property lateinit instead
private val _text: String? = whatever
val text: String get() = requireNotNull(_text)
```

- Maybe look at Kotlin *contracts* which allow you to make guarantees to the compiler about values (no example because I've never used it)

It's not really clear what you *actually want to do* though, or why this is useful. Your example is even using `val`s and assigning *null* to them. Whatever your real use case is, there's probably a better way.

(Also in case you're not aware, properties that aren't constructor parameters aren't included in the basic `data class` behaviour, i.e. its `equals`/`hashCode`/`toString` implementations. Another reason just making the types non-null helps, you can stick them in the constructor instead of having to do this logic)